# Theoretical limit to gravity detection?

Tags: gravity

Is there a calculable limit to how sensitive a gravity detector can be (in principle) imposed by the Heisenberg uncertainty principal? To detect gravity something has to move or experience some detectable force. js there a limit to the fine-grainedness of space time below which movement or force could not possibly be detected in principle?

Comment: The HUP has nothing to do with experimental error or a machine's measurement sensitivity...it's a collection of results on how the standard deviations of two measured variables obtained in *different*, yet *identical*, experiments are related to each other. So you can, in principle, measure any force, no matter how small, you just won't be able to consistently repeat the experiment, under *identical* circumstances, and get say, the velocity, with the same precision.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I remembered reading something by Alex Vilenkin about how there is a limit to the fine-grainedness--and therefore the number of possible states--of the universe, as a result of the HUP. Would this not place a limit on the minimum defection of a needle that could be in principle detected, for example?

Comment: If I remember correctly, to explore this limit, things at the discrete level, you'd need infinite energy.

Comment: The limit (in terms of spectral noise power) would be given by the temperature of the cosmic gravitational wave background and the maximal antenna gain that your detector could achieve... and the latter is basically "just" a matter of research funding.